# Wordpress function like is_category for subcategory? is_subcategory?

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

Is there a function in WordPress that will check if the page you are on is a sub-category archive page?

Like the way is_category checks if it's a category page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sub-categories use the regular category archive page by default. There is no function such as is_subcategory. But you can write your own.

Here is an example:
This will check if the current page is a sub-category. Or if you pass an ID it will check if the ID is a subcategory.

```
function is_subcategory( $cat_id = NULL ) {

        if ( !$cat_id )
            $cat_id = get_query_var( 'cat' );

        if ( $cat_id ) {

            $cat = get_category( $cat_id );
            if ( $cat->category_parent > 0 )
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the current location (without the need to specify an ID):

```
// Return type - Boolean or Object (if the latter, then check the result with is_object)
function is_subcategory($return_boolean=true) {
    $result = false;
    if (is_category()) {
        $this_category = get_queried_object();
        if (0 != $this_category->parent) // Category has a parent
            $result = $return_boolean ? true : $this_category;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The original answer appeared under the duplicated question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117133/conditional-tag-for-sub-cagtegories