# Conditional Tag for sub cagtegories?

Tags: categories, conditional-tags

We have is_category() for categories, however I'm not getting a conditional tags for subcategories. I want to enqueue script only on subcategories but on the parent.
So let's say I have a parent category 'fun' which has several sub categories like 'stories', 'arts', 'crafts' . How do I load a script only for the subcategory but not for parent 'fun'?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a category has a parent, if it does it is a child category.

```
if( is_category() ){
    $this_category = get_queried_object();
    if( 0 != $this_category->parent ){
        echo 'category has parent';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Unlike `is_category()`] `in_category()` tests only against a post's assigned categories, not ancestors (parents) of those categories.
>
> — [**Testing if a post is in a descendant category**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category)

So, [`in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page) is probably what you are after.

Based on the example cited in your question, you'd do something like this:

```
if( in_category( array( 'stories', 'arts', 'crafts' ) ) ) {

    // Do what you want...

}
```