# Parent Category and Subcategory default text generated with category

Tags: categories, taxonomy, hierarchical

I need help on something I am unable to do on my website.

I have several category and sub category on my page.
For E.g

`Food
-Apple
-Orange
Shirt
Laptop
-HP
-Dell`

I would like on each category page and sub category page a default text appearing as so:

For sub category

> The best Food Apple you can get.

For the main category

> The best Food you can get

This should be the same for all category and subcategory page.

I am using the below code for the moment but the main category is still displaying the subcategory e.g FoodApple

```
    <h2 class="supply">The best 

       <?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
            echo $term->name ;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        if ( $term->parent == !0 ) {
            echo $term->name ;
        }
    }
    ?>

 you can get </h2>
```

I would be so grateful if someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you take a look on code shown [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89512/15605) and start from there and implement your own code to get result without the need for editing templates?!

Comment: already tried but its not working